# gitlab docker ssh issue

Tags: nginx, ssh, docker, gitlab

I looked the different posts concerning gitlab, docker, and ssh issues without any help. So, I ask my question here.

I have the following setting:

- linux box with ubuntu server 14.04 and IP 192.168.1.104
- DNS: git.mydomain.com = 192.168.1.104
- A gitlab docker that I start, according to the [official doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/docker), this way:

  ```
  sudo docker run --detach --name gitlab_app --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data gitlab_image
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo docker run --detach --name gitlab_app --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 -e "GITLAB_SHELL_SSH_PORT=2222" --volumes-from gitlab_data gitlab_image
  ```
- the linux box runs an nginx which redirects (proxy_pass) git.mydomain.com to 192.168.1.104:8080
- I access git.mydomain.com without any issue, everything works.
- I generated an ssh key that I have added to my profile on gitlab and added the following lines to my ~/.ssh/config

  ```
  Host git.mydomain.com
  User git
  Port 2222
  IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- If I try

  ```
  ssh -p 2222 git@git.mydomain.com
  ```

  the connection is closed. I assume it is because only a git-shell is permitted.
- But, if I try

  ```
  mkdir test
  cd test
  git init
  touch README.md
  git add README.md
  git commit -m "first commit"
  git remote add origin git@git.domain.com:user/test.git
  git push -u origin master
  ```

  it stucks with

  ```
  Connection closed by 192.168.1.104
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  ```

I also tried with

```
    git remote add origin git@git.domain.com:2222/user/
```

and the result was the same.
Note that the logs of gitlab docker include

```
   [2015-03-06T11:04:43+00:00] INFO: group[git] created
   [2015-03-06T11:04:43+00:00] INFO: user[git] created
   [2015-03-06T11:04:44+00:00] INFO: group[gitlab-www] created
   [2015-03-06T11:04:44+00:00] INFO: user[gitlab-www] created
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you created the `test` project on gitlab via the web UI?

Comment: Yes, project created via the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have **authentication problem**.

Here are few things you can try:

- Make sure you added you public key in gitlab.
- Check permissions of you id_rsa file.
- Try temporarily disabling hosts verification with

  ```
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  ```

I have the same setup as you (docker container in VM, DNS points to VM). I also configured .ssh/config like you.

But when I log-in with ssh I get:

```
ssh -p 2222 git@gitlab
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, tomzo!
Connection to gitlab closed.
```

Git remotes do not need port 2222 configured. This is OK (works for me):

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab:lab/workflow.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab:lab/workflow.git (push)
```

And I can push and pull with git.

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```